# How to call action in createSlice() by it's type

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

my actions in slices have types. It's possible to call this action like `dispatch({type:'filter/category', payload:'change state'})`?
[image]

I've tried to use `dispatch({type:'filter/category', payload:'change state'})` but nothing change in state. Is there way to achive that in redux/toolkit or should i migrate it to redux?

**Update**
working repo: https://gitlab.com/witekmikolajczak/dynamic_reducers

i followed the documentation: https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting

**CODE**
my reducer code(documentation)

```
export interface GenericState<T> {}
export const createGenericSlice = <T, Reducers extends SliceCaseReducers<GenericState<T>>>({
  name = 'filter',
  initialState,
  reducers,
}: {
  name: string;
  initialState: GenericState<T>;
  reducers: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<GenericState<T>, Reducers>;
}) => {
  return createSlice({
    name,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      loadFilterOptions: (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state = action.payload;
        return state;
      },
      ...reducers,
    },
  });
};

export const wrappedSlice = (reducers: any, initialState: any) =>
  createGenericSlice({
    name: 'filter',
    initialState: initialState as GenericState<[]>,
    reducers: {
      ...reducers,
    },
  });
```

**Combine reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// api

const initialReducers = {};
export const createReducer = (asyncReducers = {}) => {
  return combineReducers({
    ...initialReducers,
    ...asyncReducers,
  });
};

export default createReducer;
```

**Store**

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createReducer from './rootReducer';

export function initStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: createReducer(),
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => [...getDefaultMiddleware()],
  });
}
const store = initStore();

export function injectAsyncReducer(key: any, asyncReducer: any) {
  asyncReducer[key] = asyncReducer;
  store.replaceReducer(createReducer(asyncReducer));
}

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>;

export default store;
```

**Add new reducer in hook**

```
injectAsyncReducer('test', this.reducerCollection.caseReducers.category);
```

**Problem:**
how to dispach action by it's type eg.

```
dispatch({type:"filter/load", payload:data})
```

Comment: Could you share your Reducer code?

Comment: Try this !!
first export your action like 
`export const { loadFilterOptions } = createSlice.actions`
then import it into your component and call it like
`dispatch({type: loadFilterOptions.type , payload:data})`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using redux toolkit here but you're trying to dispatch it directly via types. I'd recommend using the synchronous function available via reducer attribute in createSlice (again I'm assuming you're using RTK).

```
const filterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'filter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    filterCategory: (state, action) => {
      state.category = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { filterCategory } = filterSlice.actions;
export default filterSlice.reducer;
```

then instead just dispatching it directly, just use

```
dispatch(filterCategory());
```

Hope it helps mate. Don't hesitate to ask for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Well, unfortunately, I can't do that, because I create a reducer from an object (which is unknown - it is supposed to be dynamic) that has keys and based on these keys, I create functions using new Function () and based on this, I create reducers as in the screenshot, but I dont know if there is a possibility in redux/toolkit to refer to these reducers by type, or should I rewrite everything to a normal redux?

Comment: Do you have a working repo that we can check? Happy to review it. I think I encountered a similar scenario before but I'm just assuming here. No need to rewrite everything to normal redux, rtk will just do fine and will save you more time. The only difference there is normal redux uses rails pattern while the new implementation uses features slice. Keep in mind that in order for the dispatch to be read and fired, it's recommended to have reducers or extraReducers to access state and actions. Tapping in directly won't normally work.